# Hide an href using css

Tags: css

I have a menu item that I need to hide. It is not logical to go through all the files and remove it so I was looking for a way to hide it with CSS. Here is the code I have:

```
<li>
    <a tabindex="-1" href="index.php?option=com_eshop&view=countries">
        <span class="icon-flag"></span>
         Countries
    </a>
</li>
```

I found a few possible solutions but nothing seems to work. Here is the one that should work but I must be doing something wrong:

```
a[href="index.php?option=com_eshop&view=countries"]{ display:none; }
```

Comment: why don't you use css classes, ie. tag that link with a class and then use ``display:none```?

Answer (score 2):

That attribute selector *should* work given the HTML you provided. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/2xsu18de/).

There are several reasons why it may not be working. Here are two possibilities:

- The selector is being overwritten by another selector with a [higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). If this is the case, you could increase the specificity of your selector by adding the parent element selectors to the selector. Since it's a dropdown menu, it's likely there is a more specific selector setting something like `display: block`.
- It's also possible that's not the `href` value on your site. If this is the case, you could try using the attribute selector `[attr*=value]`. This will select all elements that *contain* instances of that value string.

  ```
  a[href*="index.php?option=com_eshop&view=countries"] {
      display:none;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the nth-child(item number) css property and hide it because you also want to hide the li because if you only hide link then there may be whitespace due to li